# How can I save data from a random amout of form elements into a SQL table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, forms

I'm making a form builder in a WordPress plugin and I have no idea how to save form data from a user made form which can be created in a plethora of different ways.

I want to save this from data to a MySQL table which there are a ton of working guides for on both this site and the rest of the www, however those work on an assumption of that the "receiving" end knows how the form is setup.

I do not have that option.

example code would be any type of form:

```
<form action= "insert.php" method= POST">
    <input type ="text" name"name">
    <input type ="number" name"phone">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

an example problem would be to suddenly add a few more input fields like:

```
<form action= "insert.php" method= POST">
    <input type ="text" name"name">
    <input type ="text" name"lastname">
    <input type ="email" name"email">
    <input type ="text" name"town">
    <input type ="number" name"zip">
    <input type ="tel" name"phone">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and then in insert.php (after connecting to DB)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $number =$_POST['phone'];
}

$query= "INSERT INTO formdata(name,phone) VALUES('$name','$number');
```

I  want a way to pretty much be able to receive any type of data from any type of form, from the easiest comment and contact form to a big 50+ parts one.

My only idea at the moment is to add support for many many MANY elements of each type but that wouldn't look good nor feel good.

Right now if I were to add more form elements in the form builder I would also have to go directly into the code and change the "receiving" part just to match that single form which would ruin the post/save function for the rest of the forms.

Comment: So you want a way to insert into columns where the name of the input represents the column, and just `insertAllForm($_POST)`?

Comment: An obvious option would be to create a "`data`" text column in the database, then just store the entire $_POST object as a JSON or php serialized string.

Comment: I don't really see the issue with having to add it in the form, and add it manually to the query. It's not like you change the inputs to your form very often?

Comment: @Qirel He wants a generic function & database schema that can handle any form, regardless of the fields.

Comment: @USDMatt refresh my answer, I gave him what he needed and went into pretty decent detail on how to accomplish this. He has 2 options.

Comment: I get that, but it's better to specify for each form which elements you want inserted. Gives you more control. It's not like you would keep changing a form very often after it's been created.

Comment: @Qirel he's building a Dynamic form builder that would be built into something like an ACP. End users aren't going to know how to build queries or even want to. They should just be able to pick and choose form elements click save and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Create your form elements in an array example:

```
<input type="text" name="elements[samplename]">
<input type="text" name="elements[samplename1]">
<input type="text" name="elements[samplename2]">
```

If you create them like this they're posted as an array in php which you can then just explode and store in the database super easily.

If you don't have checkboxes this will handle almost any use case, you can do check boxes too but it requires a little more work.

That said when the data is posted you will retrieve it with $_POST or $_GET and the result will be an associative array that will look something like this:

```
array (size=12)
  'samplename' => string 'sample' (length=6)
  'samplename1' => string 'sample 2' (length=8)
  'samplename2' => string 'sample 3' (length=8)
```

Using this method you can group the input types by array names so text types would be text[name] phone numbers would be phone[name], then using that you can iterate through the post data and separate them out by types. Using those types you can have separate relational tables that relate to a user by their ID for each input type where you can store the results.

Textbox table:
ID | User_ID | Form_ID | Value

You can also do them all in one table and just have a type variable where type represents the input field type.

- OR -

Just another though too about ways you can store them, one really simple way would be to just take the whole array and convert it into json using json encode and store that whole string, then when you need to use it decode it using json_decode.

---

**DEMO**

HTML:

```
<div id="addItem">
        <h2>Add New Element:</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="elementName" required>
        <select name="inputs" id="newInput">
            <option value="text">text</option>
            <option value="email">email</option>
            <option value="phone">phone</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="addElement" value="Add Item">

        <strong>You can add a infinite amount of parameters required or optional here</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="myFormElemets">
        <form id="myForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
            <!-- Your elements will be populated here via jquery -->
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#addElement').click(function () {
            var selectValue = $('#newInput').find(":selected").text();
            var nameValue = $('#elementName').val();

            switch (selectValue) {
                case "text":
                    $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="' + selectValue + "[" + nameValue + "]" + '">');
                    break;

                case "email":
                    $('#myForm').append('<input type="email" name="' + selectValue + "[" + nameValue + "]" + '">');
                    break;

                case "phone":
                    $('#myForm').append('<input type="tel" name="' + selectValue + "[" + nameValue + "]" + '">');
                    break;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
$sql = null;
        foreach($_POST as $array)
        {
            foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                switch ($key) {
                    case "text":
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `my_table` ('id', 'form_id', 'element_type', 'value') VALUES (NULL, '$formID', '0', '$value')";
                        break;

                    case "email":
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `my_table` ('id', 'form_id', 'element_type', 'value') VALUES (NULL, '$formID', '1', '$value')";
                        break;

                    case "phone":
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `my_table` ('id', 'form_id', 'element_type', 'value') VALUES (NULL, '$formID', '2', '$value')";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        //prepared sql insert statement here.
```

Using this sample you can save any number of elements, add infinite required parameters and much much more. Get creative! :)

Comment: Yes, but my point is if he doesn't plan to store them as a chunk of data using json or whatever case, grouping them by type using arrays in the name is the best option for storing. Then you can have different tables for different form element types that can be stored by an ID and using the arrays you know which table they belong to.

Comment: Using all elements within the `$_POST['elements']` array with your suggestion, or using `$_POST` directly with a normal table structure wouldn't be any difference. I fail to see the point.

Comment: elements is a sample name it would be more like $_POST['textboxes'] and $_POST['email'], this would keep the elements grouped, using this you can have one table that can take a form_id, a element_type, and the data from the element. Each input type has a id which can associate back to future edits and building of the form. This is a solid option for storing your data, and tracking what type of element it came from originally to keep it editable as per the point of the plugin. If you store it as one JSON blob theres no way to track what it came from.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for something like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
    }else{
        $name = '';
    }
//your code here
}
```

repeated for each field that may exist.

Then a query with all the fields in the table that can be inserted. All of them will have a value both if they are posted or if they are not.

Comment: The inputs cannot be hard coded, there can be ANY number of elements in the form builder and he can't hard code 20 text boxes, 3 selects, 3 emails and a checkbox. His code base would be massive and have to account for every name under the sun. Its a form builder plugin in word press that users can add any number of inputs to, click save and display.

Comment: then he should also take into account that the table where he would save the data wouldn't have the fields to store the data selected by the user. Sounds a bit weird...

Comment: Actually it would if you read my answer and the comments under it explains why.

Comment: Then re read it and track the comments, it's the most logical way you can store data, and track the element types at the same time for future edits and modifications.